# Is it possible to have Separate X Screen with separate sound?

Tags: xorg, sound, nvidia, tv

I have nvidia card (fx5200) that has been configured "separate x screen". So that VGA picture is on my monitor and DVI is connected with TV.

Now I'm wondering is it possible to stick another sound card into computer and have local sound near my monitor and apps that and running on the TV screen, their sound will be sent to TV (via analog line, 3.5mm jack)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Simply choose the appropriate sound card on the application whose output it's on the TV screen. Or you can use a soundserver like PulseAudio (or Jack if supported by the applications) and setup a custom routing.

Comment: Indeed, the included GNOME volume control applet may not expose all the information you desire.  In that case, please install and use pavucontrol from the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Thanks, pavucontrol somewhat works and is really easy to use. But if I run one VLC on TV screen and another on Montior, then only one sound route can be used. Better solution would be that sound output is selected based on the screen that application is running on.